# Rename a Bundle in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I have started using more 3rd party bundles and some of them require your own specific bundle to integrate with, such as the Sonata user bundle directs you to create an ApplicationSonataUserBundle.

This was easy to set up, but now I think it appropriate for me to rename the bundle to put under the rest of my app bundles instead of 'Application' bundle name.

Is the only way to do this to do a search and replace through all of the source code?  I have some routes and events that use the 'Application' naming convention and all of those will need and change so this will not be a simple find and replace.  Has anyone else gone though this and had any unexpected problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search and replace is the first phase, yes.

Another thing that needs to be done is to go to `Dependency Injection` directory of the bundle and rename the `.php` file there which bears the name of the bundle...

Comment: This was not much fun, but needed to be done and thanks for the heads up on renaming the file.  Always important to think ahead before expanding too much!

Comment: Agree :) I had similar situation of 6 code copies of project only to differ by a namespace :( (ok, and some very minor things). The idea was to develop new feature at first copy and then replicate it to others. After a while, I've fully adopted VCS branching (`git` to be more specific) and made my life much easier. :)